# How do I, after opening the iOS 5 built-in dictionary, look up the definition of a word that appears in a dictionary definition?

Tags: ios, dictionary

I can look up the definition of any word that I can select in iOS.  However, once the dictionary is open, I can't figure out how to further look up the definition of a word that appears in the dictionary definition.  This seems like basic dictionary software functionality.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to do it. I think that’s really stupid. Though I remember being able to do that in iBooks when it was first released, before iOS had a built in dictionary.